# Initializing AWS IoT JavaScript client within Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-iot, amazon-iam

I am using the [AWS IoT JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js) as part of an application which is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. When attempting to initialize the client I get the following error: `Failed to read credentials from /tmp/.aws/credentials`

This makes sense because my Elastic Beanstalk environment gets access to AWS services through its IAM role, rather than through a credentials file. Thus, how do I initialize the client when my environment is using an IAM role, rather than a file?

Here is the code I am using:

```
const awsIot = require("aws-iot-device-sdk");

const device = awsIot.device({
    host: "myhost.region.amazonaws.com",
    protocol: "wss",
});
```

Comment: have you configured a service role or instance profile? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html

Comment: I am using the same IAM role for both the service role and instance profile. Also, it looks like Elastic Beanstalk now uses two instance profiles (one for the service and one for logging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/133), it looks like I need to get temporary credentials either through STS, Cognito, or some other service and [refresh the client](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#awsiotdeviceupdatewebsocketcredentialsaccesskeyid-secretkey-sessiontoken-expiration) with these credentials periodically before they expire.